# Triggering change and load events on ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a code which runs on change event of select box `#type` as id. The element is loaded via ajax in bootstrap modal window. It works fine on change event by showing/hiding relevant elements and firing an ajax request.

Now I want to run it everytime, ajax content is loaded as well, apart from change event, because sometimes a default value is loaded for `#type` element and I want to show/hide elements and fire ajax request on ajax content load that time.

I tried to use `load` event like this,

`$(document).on('load change', '#geo-form #type', function () {...`

but id didn't work. How can I make this work.

Here is the default working code, as of now.

```
$(document).on('change', '#geo-form #type', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
    if (value == '') {
        $.getJSON(url('ajax/divisions'), null, function (data) {
            $("#geo-form #division_id").html('');
            $("#geo-form #division_id").append(
                $("<option></option>").text('Select one').val('')
            );
            $.each(data, function (id, name) {
                $("#geo-form #division_id").append(
                    $("<option></option>").text(name).val(id)
                );
            });
        });
    }
    switch (value) {
        case 'district':
            $('#geo-form .division').removeClass('hide');
            $('#geo-form .district').addClass('hide');
            $('#geo-form .tehsil').addClass('hide');
            $('#geo-form .block').addClass('hide');
            break;
        case 'tehsil':
            $('#geo-form .division').removeClass('hide');
            $('#geo-form .district').removeClass('hide');
            $('#geo-form .tehsil').addClass('hide');
            $('#geo-form .block').addClass('hide');
            break;
        case 'block':
            $('#geo-form .division').removeClass('hide');
            $('#geo-form .district').removeClass('hide');
            $('#geo-form .tehsil').removeClass('hide');
            $('#geo-form .block').addClass('hide');
            break;
        case 'village':
            $('#geo-form .division').removeClass('hide');
            $('#geo-form .district').removeClass('hide');
            $('#geo-form .tehsil').removeClass('hide');
            $('#geo-form .block').removeClass('hide');
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: So trigger it `$(document).trigger("change")`

Comment: Will it apply to ajax loaded content as well?

Comment: Did you try it and see what happens?

Comment: Tried, but it didn't work, as the content is loaded via ajax.

Comment: Yes, you call it after the content is loaded with Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) it manually on re-create :

```
$("#geo-form #division_id").trigger('change');
```

Comment: `change` event is working fine. I just want it to trigger on page load as well, but the content in itself including triggering element is loaded via ajax.

Comment: I know. Just run this code when you load or reload the content. This is not  actually the change event, it's forcing the handler to run.

Comment: Since I am loaded content using bootstrap modal, I tried this code in `loaded.bs.modal` event of the modal component. The bootstrap event is triggering on content load via ajax, but `$(document).trigger('change')` is not triggering.

Comment: Try putting the code in the answer right after the block $.each(data, function (id, name) { ...

Comment: But `$.each...` will only trigger on change, not on page load.

Comment: On `document.ready`, `$("#geo-form #division_id")` will  not be available

Comment: If it is not available on page load ($(document).ready is the page load), how you will expect something from it on page load?

Comment: Since the element is loaded via ajax, how come `$("#geo-form #division_id")` will be available on `document.ready`??